# Unable to append the unity iOS build

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I have updated my unity project from 5.6.2f1 to 2017.3.1f1.i am unable to append the unity iOS build with my previous build which is created by unity 5.6.2f1.i don't want to replace my previous version unity build because I have native support by that code.unity showing this popup

build folder already exist and created by other unity iPhone version or other target support device would u replace it.please suggest what should I do?

Comment: I would suggest that whatever modifications you need to make to the xcode project be put in a post process script so that any time you make a build the modifications are applied automatically.

Comment: but how it will help in my case please can u explain it

Comment: Well, you haven't really explained your case very well. It sounds like you have a project you built for iOS, and after Unity wrote the xcode project you made modifications. My suggestion is to make those modifications with code rather than manually. If you have a different issue then you'll need to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

always keep backup of your existing projects while upgrading unity, in this case, you should first make a backup of 'build' folder(copy it to another place or make a zip of it) then replace the folder with the existing folder.
in case your project gets broken, just restore your backup folder.